# Get abbr inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element, abbr

I have this:

```
<th class="day-heading mon" scope="col">
  <abbr title="Lunes">L</abbr>
</th>
```

I need to access the abbr and change the innerHTML and title. How do I do that?
I tried doing...

```
jQuery('.day-heading mon > abbr');
```

but I can't modify the properties from there.

Comment: if you want the selector to be on both classes do jQuery('.day-heading.mon > abbr'); (without the space and put in a period). Once you have the correct selector you can use .attr() and other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just `$("abbr")`.

```
$("abbr").attr("title","something")
$("abbr").html("stuff")
```

If you want to select the "abbr" inside `<th class="day-heading mon" >`, do:

`$("th.day-heading.mon abbr")`

Comment: What if there are bunch of them on the page? The OP seems to be specific about that selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the inner HTML of selected elements with the [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) jQuery function and their `title` attributes with [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName) jQuery function. Therefore, you could do:

```
$('.day-heading mon > abbr').attr("title", "HST")
$('.day-heading mon > abbr').html("Hubble Space Telescope")
```